# Difference between .cma, .cmo, .cmx files and how to use them correctly in compilation?

Tags: c++, compilation, ocaml

I am new to the OCaml and I'm confused with the file of **.cma**, **.cmo** and **.cmx**. Sometimes I have to include a .cma file in the compile command but sometimes I have to include a .cmo file.

Why is there a such difference for library? Is it the same concept in C++ as library and include path?

Example: ocamlc -o executable str.cma extstring.cmo mycode.ml

Thanks

Comment: The overview of the [byte-code](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/comp.html#sec263) and [native compiler](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/native.html#sec283) in the manual explain quite well the menagerie of files related to OCaml compilation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may think that `.cmo` is library, but it's not.

- `.cmo` is bytecode object file. It's like `.class` in Java.
- `.cma` is bytecode library. It's produce by archiving some `.cmo` into `.cma`
- `.cmx` is produced by `ocamlopt` (the native-code compiler). Main output files of `ocamlopt` is `.o` but `ocamlopt` also produce it.

To create executable files, we arrange `.cmo` and `.cma` like `ocamlc -o executable lib.cma a.cmo b.cmo ...` to link them.
You can write `.ml` here instead of `.cmo` but it's the same as compiling `.ml` with `-c` and link the `.cmo` and other files.

---

For your deep undestanding, it's better to check how each files (related to ocaml) are produced.
Let's see what files are produce by `ocamlc` and `ocamlopt`.

```
[/tmp/test] ls
test.ml
[/tmp/test] cat ./test.ml 
let id x = x
[/tmp/test] ocamlc -c /tmp/test/test.ml 
[/tmp/test] ls
test.cmi  test.cmo  test.ml
[/tmp/test]
```

Now I compiled `test.ml` file and compile it with `ocamlc` with `-c` option
(the content of `test.ml` is not matter here).
You see `ocamlc` outputs two files:

- `test.cmi`: Compiled interface file. This file includes type information of functions, variables in `test.ml` for separate compilation.
- `test.cmo`: Bytecode object file: It's like `.class` file in Java.

We use `.cmo` files to create executable files.

```
[/tmp/test] ocamlc -c test.ml 
[/tmp/test] ocamlc -o a.out test.cmo
[/tmp/test] ls
a.out  test.cmi  test.cmo  test.ml
```

You see `a.out` file are produced via the `.cmo` file.

`.cma` are library files. These are produced by composing multiple `.cmo` files.

```
[/tmp/test] ls
test.ml lib.ml
[/tmp/test] cat lib.ml 
let i = Test.id 1
let j = Test.id 2
[/tmp/test] ocamlc -c test.ml; ocamlc -c lib.ml
[/tmp/test] ls
lib.cmi  lib.cmo  lib.ml  test.cmi  test.cmo  test.ml
[/tmp/test] ocamlc -a -o testlib.cma ./test.cmo lib.cmo
[/tmp/test] ls
lib.cmi  lib.cmo  lib.ml  test.cmi  test.cmo  test.ml  testlib.cma
```

Now I create `lib.ml` (which use `id` function in `test.ml`) and compile `test.ml` and `lib.ml`, then link them to create `testlib.cma` (option `-a` means creating a library).
You can see `.cma` is just packed with `.cmo` files.

To use the library, we just arrange it with other object files.

```
[/tmp/test] cat user.ml
let _ = print_int (Lib.i + Lib.j)
[/tmp/test] ocamlc -c user.ml
[/tmp/test] ocamlc -o a.out testlib.cma user.cmo
```

Finally, let's check what files are produce by `ocamlopt`.

```
[/tmp/test] ocamlopt -c ./test.ml 
[/tmp/test] ls
test.cmi  test.cmx  test.ml  test.o
```

`ocamlopt` produces

- `test.o`: Native object file
- `test.cmi`: Compiled interaface file
- `test.cmx`: Also native object file, but it is mainly used for inlining functions across files!!!

Comment: You answer is way more complete than mine but if you speak about `.cmx` you should also mention `.cmxa`. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

So, the difference is here (when there's a `x` in the file extension, it means it's a native-code compiled object so that it runs faster. The `cmx` files are obtained with `ocamlopt` and the `cmo` files with `ocamlc`) :

- `.cma` / `.cmxa` -> libraries that are already available for the programmer (standard libraries and libraries you installed)
- `.cmo` / `.cmx` -> object files corresponding to your .ml files

**TL;DR** : `.cm(x)a` files were not created by you, `.cm(o|x)` files were.

Comment: Your explanation helps to remember these extensions too! Thank you man